# How to display a legend in Plottable.js multiple plot

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, plottable

I have the following code:

```js
var indata = [{
  'sample': "Foo",
  "pies_pct": [{
    "score": 6.7530200000000002,
    "celltype": "Bcells"
  }, {
    "score": 11.432763461538459,
    "celltype": "DendriticCells"
  }]

}, {
  'sample': "Bar",
  "pies_pct": [{
    "score": 26.8530200000000002,
    "celltype": "Bcells"
  }, {
    "score": 31.432763461538459,
    "celltype": "DendriticCells"
  }]

}, ];



processData(indata);

function processData(data) {

  pies = data.map(function(data) {
    return {
      title: data.sample,
      dataset: data.pies_pct
    };


  });

  buildPlots();
}

function buildPlots() {
  var $pieContainer = $('#sample-pies');

  pies.forEach(function(pie, index) {
    var elementId = "sample-pie-" + index;

    $(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg'))
      .css({
        width: '200px',
        height: '200px',
        display: 'inline-block'
      })
      .attr('id', elementId)
      .appendTo($pieContainer);


    plotSamplePie(pie.title, pie.dataset, '#' + elementId);
  });


}




function plotSamplePie(title, purity_data, targetElement) {
  var scale = new Plottable.Scales.Linear();
  var tableau20 = ['#1F77B4', '#FF7F0E', '#2CA02C', '#D62728',
    '#9467BD', '#8C564B', '#CFECF9', '#7F7F7F', '#BCBD22', '#17BECF'
  ];
  var colorScale = new Plottable.Scales.Color();
  var legend = new Plottable.Components.Legend(colorScale);
  colorScale.range(tableau20);




  var titleLabel = new Plottable.Components.TitleLabel(title);
  var plot = new Plottable.Plots.Pie()
    .addDataset(new Plottable.Dataset(purity_data))
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return d.score;
    }, colorScale)
    .sectorValue(function(d) {
      return d.score;
    }, scale)
    .labelsEnabled(true);


  new Plottable.Components.Table([
    [titleLabel],
    [plot]
  ]).renderTo(targetElement);

}


function drawPieLegend(targetElement) {
  new Plottable.Components.Legend(colorScale)
    .renderTo(targetElement);
}


drawPieLegend('#pies-legend')
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plottable.js/1.15.0/plottable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.1/basic/jquery.qtip.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>

<body>


  My Plot

  <!-- Show histograms -->
  <div id="sample-pies"></div>
  
  Legend here:
  <div id="pies-legend"></div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plottable.js/1.15.0/plottable.js"></script>





</body>

</html>
```

What I want do do is to display **one** legend for both pie charts under `'#pies-legend'` as the target element called by the function `drawPieLegend()`. But why it does not show up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`colorScale` is defined inside `plotSamplePie()`, so it doesn't appear in the scope of `drawPieLegend()`. Declaring `colorScale` outside both functions will make it possible for both functions to access it (although this is a bit messy since it is now a global variable). It'd probably be cleaner to create `colorScale` inside the processing function, then pass it to the functions that make the pies and the legend separately. Here's a quick attempt at fixing it:

```js
var indata = [{
  'sample': "Foo",
  "pies_pct": [{
    "score": 6.7530200000000002,
    "celltype": "Bcells"
  }, {
    "score": 11.432763461538459,
    "celltype": "DendriticCells"
  }]

}, {
  'sample': "Bar",
  "pies_pct": [{
    "score": 26.8530200000000002,
    "celltype": "Bcells"
  }, {
    "score": 31.432763461538459,
    "celltype": "DendriticCells"
  }]

}, ];

              
var colorScale = new Plottable.Scales.Color();
var tableau20 = ['#1F77B4', '#FF7F0E', '#2CA02C', '#D62728',
    '#9467BD', '#8C564B', '#CFECF9', '#7F7F7F', '#BCBD22', '#17BECF'
];
colorScale.range(tableau20);

processData(indata);

function processData(data) {

  pies = data.map(function(data) {
    return {
      title: data.sample,
      dataset: data.pies_pct
    };


  });

  buildPlots();
}

function buildPlots() {
  var $pieContainer = $('#sample-pies');

  pies.forEach(function(pie, index) {
    var elementId = "sample-pie-" + index;

    $(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg'))
      .css({
        width: '200px',
        height: '200px',
        display: 'inline-block'
      })
      .attr('id', elementId)
      .appendTo($pieContainer);


    plotSamplePie(pie.title, pie.dataset, '#' + elementId);
  });


}




function plotSamplePie(title, purity_data, targetElement) {
  var scale = new Plottable.Scales.Linear();
  var titleLabel = new Plottable.Components.TitleLabel(title);
  var plot = new Plottable.Plots.Pie()
    .addDataset(new Plottable.Dataset(purity_data))
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return d.celltype;
    }, colorScale)
    .sectorValue(function(d) {
      return d.score;
    }, scale)
    .labelsEnabled(true);


  new Plottable.Components.Table([
    [titleLabel],
    [plot]
  ]).renderTo(targetElement);

}


function drawPieLegend(targetElement) {
  new Plottable.Components.Legend(colorScale)
    .maxEntriesPerRow(Infinity)
    .renderTo(targetElement);
}


drawPieLegend('#pies-legend');
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plottable.js/1.15.0/plottable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.1/basic/jquery.qtip.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>

<body>


  My Plot

  <!-- Show histograms -->
  <div id="sample-pies"></div>
  
  Legend here:
  <svg id="pies-legend" height="50" width="400"></svg>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plottable.js/1.15.0/plottable.js"></script>





</body>

</html>
```

Note also the change from

```
.attr("fill", function(d) {
  return d.score;
}, colorScale)
```

to

```
.attr("fill", function(d) {
  return d.celltype;
}, colorScale)
```

which causes the colors to be driven by `celltype` rather than `score`.

Comment: Thanks. But we'd like the legend to have just **two** colours: for `Bcells` and `DendriticCells`. Moreover the value of the legend should be `Bcells` and `DendriticCells`, not 6.75 etc2. How can we modify your code?

Comment: I amended the above comment to drive the fill color based on celltype.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add legend to new Plottable.Components.Table().

```
new Plottable.Components.Table([
    [titleLabel],
    [plot],
    [legend]
  ]).renderTo(targetElement);
```

Go through below snippet.

```js
var indata = [{
  'sample': "Foo",
  "pies_pct": [{
    "score": 6.7530200000000002,
    "celltype": "Bcells"
  }, {
    "score": 11.432763461538459,
    "celltype": "DendriticCells"
  }]

}, {
  'sample': "Bar",
  "pies_pct": [{
    "score": 26.8530200000000002,
    "celltype": "Bcells"
  }, {
    "score": 31.432763461538459,
    "celltype": "BCells"
  }]

}, ];



processData(indata);

function processData(data) {

  pies = data.map(function(data) {
    return {
      title: data.sample,
      dataset: data.pies_pct
    };


  });

  buildPlots();
}

function buildPlots() {
  var $pieContainer = $('#sample-pies');

  pies.forEach(function(pie, index) {
    var elementId = "sample-pie-" + index;

    $(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg'))
      .css({
        width: '200px',
        height: '200px',
        display: 'inline-block'
      })
      .attr('id', elementId)
      .appendTo($pieContainer);


    plotSamplePie(pie.title, pie.dataset, '#' + elementId);
  });


}




function plotSamplePie(title, purity_data, targetElement) {
  var scale = new Plottable.Scales.Linear();
  var tableau20 = ['#1F77B4', '#FF7F0E', '#2CA02C', '#D62728',
    '#9467BD', '#8C564B', '#CFECF9', '#7F7F7F', '#BCBD22', '#17BECF'
  ];
  var colorScale = new Plottable.Scales.Color();
  var legend = new Plottable.Components.Legend(colorScale);
  colorScale.range(tableau20);




  var titleLabel = new Plottable.Components.TitleLabel(title);
  var plot = new Plottable.Plots.Pie()
    .addDataset(new Plottable.Dataset(purity_data))
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return d.score;
    }, colorScale)
    .sectorValue(function(d) {
      return d.score;
    }, scale)
    .labelsEnabled(true);


  new Plottable.Components.Table([
    [titleLabel],
    [plot],
    [legend]
  ]).renderTo(targetElement);

}


function drawPieLegend(targetElement) {
  new Plottable.Components.Legend(colorScale)
    .renderTo(targetElement);
}


drawPieLegend('#pies-legend')
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plottable.js/1.15.0/plottable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.1/basic/jquery.qtip.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>

<body>


  My Plot

  <!-- Show histograms -->
  <div id="sample-pies"></div>
  
  Legend here:
  <div id="pies-legend"></div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plottable.js/1.15.0/plottable.js"></script>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But that's not what I want. We want to display **one** legend for both pie chart. And the legend content should be for *Dendritic cell* and *B Cell* not its value.

Comment: Try using legend.renderTo("svg#legend_example"); But this need to be work on as shown in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3fpw33oL/

Comment: Thanks. Not quite there. By doing that you are appending multiple chart legend to one plot.